# How to use a list of values to find the same values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, helper

[streamingHistory dateframe for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ia7DD.png) I have a dataframe of my Spotify data and a list of my top 50 most popular artists. I want to use this list to find every corresponding artist without passing through my dataframe 25 times.

```
# Find most popular artists from 2019
topFifty = streamingHistory[streamingHistory["year"] == 2019]["artistName"].value_counts().index[:50]
topFifty = streamingHistory[streamingHistory["artistName"] in top2019]
```

This code gives me a type error

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

I currently now have this (which works), but I'm curious if there is a way to do it without applying a helper function...

```
topFifty = streamingHistory[streamingHistory["year"] == 2019]["artistName"].value_counts().index[:25]


def findArtists(row):
    if (row["artistName"] in topFifty) & row["year"] == 2019:
        return row

df = streamingHistory.apply(findArtists, axis=1).dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Try this : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy where` it allows to constraint selection with conditions :

Example :

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"A" : np.random.choice(["blue", "red", "green", "yellow", 
                   "purple", "black", "white", "brown","golden", "silver"], 200),                                            
                   "year" : np.random.choice([2011, 2012, 2013, 2018, 2019], 200)})

ref_list = ["silver", "golden", "brown", "blue"] 

df["matches"] = np.where((df["A"].isin(ref_list)) & (df["year"] == 2019), 1, 0)
```

In your case the `ref_list` would be the artists' names, and you can check if the streaming history artists fall within that list. Then, you also require that the year is 2019. Only when those two conditions are met will `numpy where` return a `1`.